# ie9 not supporting geolocation?

Tags: geolocation, internet-explorer-9

Greetings Everyone,
       I am creating a web application that uses the Geolocation API to locate the end user. It works great on almost every platform I can think of except for Internet Explorer 9. Things get a little stranger though. If I have my Google Toolbar loaded into my Internet Explorer browser window, everything sails smoothly. Here is the offending chunk of code that I have been working with:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
            var locationMarker = null;
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
                function( position ){
                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);    
                    if (!locationMarker) {
                        locationMarker = addMarker(
                            position.coords.latitude,
                            position.coords.longitude,
                            "Initial Position"
                        );
                    }
                    else{
                        updateMarker(
                            locationMarker,
                            position.coords.latitude,
                            position.coords.longitude,
                            "Updated / Accurate Position"
                        );
                    };
                    map.setCenter(point);
                    if (map.zoom < 17){
                        map.setZoom(17);
                    };
                },
                function( error ){
                    console.log( "Something went wrong: ", error );
                },
                {
                    timeout: (5 * 1000),
                    maximumAge: (1000 * 60 * 15),
                    enableHighAccuracy: true
                }
            );
        }
        else {
            alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser");
        }
```

Whenever I access my application with Internet Explorer 9 I get the "Geolocation is not supported by this browser" alert. That is unless I have my Google Toolbar active. If the Google Toolbar is active however, then the Google Toolbar handles the permissions.

How do I get geolocation to work in IE9? My application works flawlessly in Safari, Firefox, Chrome, iOS and Android. I am totally stumped.

Thanks, Tyler Waring

Answer (score 4):

user1303379,

IE9 and IE10 both support geolocation, however earlier versions of IE do not support it ( reference http://caniuse.com/#feat=geolocation ). Here is a blog post by IE about geolocation in IE9 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/02/17/w3c-geolocation-api-in-ie9.aspx and here is a test page using `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` like you are above.

For browsers that don't support geolocation you may consider using one of the geolocation polyfills listed here https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

IE9 & IE10 ask the user if they would like to share their location http://cl.ly/image/0X0o2F0s1N03 My guess is that you may have denied access to your location at some point.

The Google Toolbar added a feature to determine geolocation back in the IE8 days http://googletoolbarhelp.blogspot.com/2010/02/google-toolbar-6413211732-for-ie.html From what you describe it sounds like the Google Toolbar started to provide geolocation since the native IE9 geolocation was denied access.